# BTRFS Multi Disk / Balancing

Tags: debian, btrfs

I have an existing BTRFS drive (/dev/sde), I added a new drive to the system, mounted it and formatted as BTRFS in gparted and then I get:

```
sudo btrfs fi show

Label: none  uuid: f54ed81a-2d6a-4cf7-88d3-b8538c2b27c6
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 512.00KiB
    devid    1 size 5.46TiB used 2.06GiB path /dev/sdd1

Label: none  uuid: 01dba537-b5c4-44f6-b198-a03972c4196f
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 1.69TiB
    devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 1.71TiB path /dev/sde
```

.

```
sudo btrfs filesystem df /mnt/local/int001
```

returns

```
Data, single: total=1.70TiB, used=1.68TiB
System, DUP: total=8.00MiB, used=208.00KiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=0.00B
Metadata, DUP: total=3.00GiB, used=2.11GiB
Metadata, single: total=8.00MiB, used=0.00B
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

I want to convert this to RAID 1, is there any issue with what you see here, should I be able to do a conversion to raid now and how would I do it?

I've tried:

```
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/local/int002
ERROR: error during balancing '/mnt/local/int002' - Invalid argument
```

There may be more info in syslog - try dmesg | tail

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made is that you created two separate BTRFS filesystems. You can see in the output of `sudo btrfs fi` the two filesystems, each with one device.

To fix it, use the `btrfs device add` command to add the new disk to the existing filesystem. THEN do the rebalance.

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-device

Comment: I did wonder if that was the case, I'll try to 'add' a little later and report back, thnx.